# Iterating a api dictionary in ForEach

Tags: api, dictionary, swiftui, foreach, iteration

How to Iterate a API dictionary in ForEach. I have a dictionary and it consists of another dictionary in it. How to display those dictionary values in contentView?

My api structs:

```
struct userDataModel: Codable {
    let status: Bool?
    let message: String?
    let data: DataClass
}
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let id, phoneNumber, email, countrycode: String?
    let loginType: String?
    let otp: Int?
    let bookingInfo, cancellationInfo: [Any?]
    let token: String?
    let isHost: Bool?
    let wishList: [String]
    let contacts, review: [Any?]
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String?
    let v: Int?
    let dob, firstName, lastName: String?
    let isOnline: Bool?
    let lastSeen: String?
    let isExperience: Bool?
}
```

ContentView code:

```
struct UserData: View {
    
    @StateObject var api = userData()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(api.responses!, id:\.self) { todo in
            Text(todo.firstName!)
        }
        .onAppear {
            api.loadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Network Class Published variables:

@Published var records: userDataModel?
@Published var responses: DataClass?

Comment: What is the type of `responses`? Also, unrelated: are you aware that unwrapping with `!` is unsafe and can lead to crashes?

Comment: @jnpdx Actually that's not an issue for me here. I'm receiving "Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'DataClass' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'" error inside view. So what's the possible way to iterate these dictionaries and display it's content inside a view.

Comment: `api.responses` is probably of type `DataClass`, but the
 `ForEach` needs an array, like `[DataClass]`.

Comment: Okay, so `responses` is just a single `DataClass`? Where is the "dictionary"  you're referring to? Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: @jnpdx Okay, I have added network class variables in my question

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine so do I need to convert it to an Array?

Comment: You only have one `DataClass`, there is no need for a `ForEach`. Try something like `Text(api.responses?.firstName ?? "no name")`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Okay thanks a lot, I tried the same approach yesterday but it didn't worked. don't know What I have missed before. but now its fine.

Comment: Note, use uppercase for types, e.g. `UserDataModel`.
There is no need for `@Published var responses: DataClass?`, the
 `@Published var records: UserDataModel?` already has the `DataClass` in the
 `data` property, just use that, for example, `records.data.firstName ...` instead.

Comment: Unrelated but don't you get an error that  `DataClass` cannot be decoded because `Any` is not supported?

Comment: @vadian no I'm not getting any errors. I am using this same method all my api structs.

Comment: Hard to believe you can compile `struct DataClass: Codable` when it contains `Any`. I get errors, `Type DataClass does not conform to protocol Decodable` same for `Encodable`

Comment: Okay I misread the question. Yes I am receiving the same error "Type 'DataClass' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable or Encodable'" but I just command those Any properties, because I am not using it in my views. I just go with the properties  which i really need in my network class and views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer provided by @workingdog support Ukraine, No need of ForEach here. Tried as Text(api.responses?.firstName ?? "no name") and in network class @Published var records: UserDataModel? is enough to bring the details out.